# animation lets view jump

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I created a list of cells which are collapsable. It works quite well, but the title headed jumps around while being animated, as you can see in this small video. It should stay put in place. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

A compilable code can be found here: https://gitlab.com/vikingosegundo/brighter-hue

[image: jumping animation]

```
//  LightCell.swift

let rowHeight = 36.0
let collapsedCellHeight = 80.0
let uncollapsedCellHeight = 180.0
let material:Material = .thickMaterial

struct LightCell: View {
    init(light: Light, rootHandler: @escaping (Message) -> ()) {
        self.rootHandler  = rootHandler
        self.light        = light
        self.isOn         = light.isOn
        self.hue          = light.hue
        self.sat          = light.saturation
        self.bri          = light.brightness
        self.ct           = Double(-light.ct)
        self.interface    = light.display
        self.selectedMode = light.modes.contains(.hsb) ? .hsb : .ct
        self.values       = light.modes.contains(.hsb) ? .hsb(light.hue, light.saturation, light.brightness) : .ct(light.ct, light.brightness)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        cellLayout
            .frame(  height: isCollapsed ? collapsedCellHeight : uncollapsedCellHeight)
            .modifier(Height(isCollapsed ? collapsedCellHeight : uncollapsedCellHeight))
            .swipeActions(edge: .leading ) { toggleColorMode }
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) { toggleInterface }
            .listRowBackground( bgColor )
            .tint(hsbColor(opacity: 0.5))
            .padding(.top,    15)
            .padding(.bottom, 15)
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .onChange(of:light.ct        ) { ct = Double(-$0); values = .ct (-$0,                         light.brightness) }
            .onChange(of:light.hue       ) { hue = $0;         values = .hsb(-$0,       light.saturation, light.brightness) }
            .onChange(of:light.saturation) { sat = $0;         values = .hsb(light.hue, $0,               light.brightness) }
            .onChange(of:light.brightness) { bri = $0;         values = .hsb(light.hue, light.saturation, $0              ) }
    }
    
    private let rootHandler: (Message) -> ()
    private let light: Light
    @EnvironmentObject
    private var viewState: ViewState
    
    @State private var values: Values
    @State private var isOn       : Bool
    @State private var hue        : Double
    @State private var sat        : Double
    @State private var bri        : Double
    @State private var ct         : Double
    @State private var interface    : Interface
    @State private var startPoint   : CGPoint?
    @State private var currentPoint : CGPoint?
    @State private var isCollapsed  : Bool = true
    @State private var selectedMode : Light.Mode
}

private
extension LightCell {
    private
    var cellLayout: some View {
        VStack {
            cellheader;
            if light.modes.contains(.hsb) || light.modes.contains(.ct) {
                switch (selectedMode, light.display) {
                case (.ct, .slider):
                    Spacer()   .isCollapsed(isCollapsed)
                    ctSliderRow.isCollapsed(isCollapsed)
                case (.hsb, .slider):
                    Spacer()    .isCollapsed(isCollapsed)
                    hueSliderRow.isCollapsed(isCollapsed);
                    satSliderRow.isCollapsed(isCollapsed)
                case (_, .scrubbing):
                    scrubbingView.isCollapsed(isCollapsed)
                }
            }
            briSliderRow
        }
    }
    private
    var toggleColorMode: some View {
        HStack {
        if !isCollapsed{
            let indexedModes = light
                .modes
                .filter { $0 != selectedMode }
                .enumerated()
                .map { (idx: $0.offset, mode: $0.element) }
            ForEach(indexedModes, id: \.idx) { i in
                Button { selectedMode = i.mode } label: { image(for: i.mode) }
            }}
        }
    }
    private
    var toggleInterface: some View {
        HStack {
        if !isCollapsed{
            Button {
                rootHandler(.lighting(.change(.display(light.display == .slider ? .scrubbing : .slider), on:light)))
            } label: { Label("", systemImage:
                                light.display == .slider
                             ? "slider.horizontal.below.rectangle"
                             : "slider.horizontal.3")
            }}
        }
    }
    private
    var cellheader: some View {
        HStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation { isCollapsed.toggle() }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName:"chevron.up")
                    .foregroundColor(hsbColor(opacity:0.75))
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .rotationEffect( .radians(isCollapsed ? .pi : 0.0))
            }
            titleLabel
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            Spacer()
            toogle
        }
        .rowStyle(height:rowHeight)
    }
    private
    var titleLabel: some View {
        Text("\(light.name)")
            .bold()
            .dynamicTypeSize(.xLarge)
            .fixedSize()
    }
    private
    var toogle: some View {
        Toggle("", isOn: $isOn)
            .onChange(of: isOn) { _ in
                switch (light.isOn, isOn) {
                case (true, false): rootHandler(.lighting(.turn(light,.off)))
                case (false, true): rootHandler(.lighting(.turn(light,.on )))
                case (  _  ,  _  ): ()
                }
            }
    }

    private
    var scrubbingKnob: some View {
        HStack {
        Spacer()
        Circle()
            .fill(
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [hsbColor(saturation:1.0, opacity: 0.5),
                                                           hsbColor(saturation:1.0, opacity: 0.5),
                                                           hsbColor(saturation:0.1, opacity: 0.5),
                                                           hsbColor(saturation:0.1, opacity: 0.5)]),
                               startPoint:.top, endPoint:.bottom)
            )}
            .frame(minWidth: 20, maxWidth: 20, minHeight:20)
            .offset(x:(currentPoint?.x ?? 0) - (startPoint?.x ?? 0), y:(currentPoint?.y ?? 0) - (startPoint?.y ?? 0))
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(
                    minimumDistance: 5,
                    coordinateSpace: .global
                ).onChanged{ n in
                    if let startpoint = startPoint {
                        switch selectedMode {
                        case .hsb:setHueAndSaturationFor(
                            distanceX: ( n.location.x ) - (startpoint.x),
                            distanceY: ( n.location.y ) - (startpoint.y))
                        case .ct: setCTfor(
                            distanceX: ( n.location.x ) - (startpoint.x),
                            distanceY: ( n.location.y ) - (startpoint.y))
                        }
                    }
                    switch startPoint == nil {
                    case true : startPoint   = n.location
                    case false: currentPoint = n.location
                    }}
                .onEnded { _ in startPoint = nil; currentPoint = nil } ).padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
    private
    var scrubbingView: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                scrubbingKnob
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
    private
    var ctSliderRow: some View {
        HStack {
            Button {
                rootHandler( .lighting(.increase(.colortemp,by:10.pt,on:light)) )
            } label: {
                Image(systemName:"thermometer.snowflake")
                    .foregroundStyle(ctColor(ct:(Double(light.ct) * 1.2)))
                    .accessibility(label:Text("increase color temperature"))
            }.frame(width: 24)
            Slider(value: $ct, in: (-500)...(-153)) { _ in rootHandler( .lighting(.apply(.values(.ct(Int(-ct),bri)),on:light))) }
            .accessibility(label:Text("change color temperature"))
            Button {
                rootHandler( .lighting(.decrease(.colortemp,by:10.pt,on:light)) )
            } label: {
                Image(systemName:"thermometer.sun")
                    .foregroundStyle(ctColor(ct:(Double(light.ct) * 0.8)))
                    .accessibility(label:Text("decrease color temperature"))
            }.frame(width: 24)
        }
        .rowStyle(height: (selectedMode == .ct && !isCollapsed) ? rowHeight : 0)
        .opacity((selectedMode == .ct && !isCollapsed) ? 1.0 : 0.0)

    }
    private
    var briSliderRow: some View {
        slider(
            bind: $bri,
            leading:
                    .init(action: {
                        rootHandler( .lighting(.decrease(.brightness,by:10.pt,on:light)) ) },
                          image: .system("sun.min"),
                          color: hsbColor(brightness: min(max(light.brightness - 0.05, 0.1), 1.0)),
                          accessibility: "decrease brightness"),
            slider:
                    .init(action: { rootHandler( .lighting(.apply(.values(.bri(bri)),on:light))) },
                        accessibility:"change brightness"),
            trailing:
                    .init(action: {
                        rootHandler( .lighting(.increase(.brightness,by:10.pt,on:light)) ) },
                        image: .system("sun.max.fill"),
                        color: hsbColor(brightness: min(max(light.brightness + 0.05, 0.1), 1.0)),
                        accessibility: "increase brightness")
        ).rowStyle(height: rowHeight)
    }
    private
    var hueSliderRow: some View {
        slider(
            bind: $hue,
            leading:
                    .init(action: { rootHandler( .lighting(.decrease(.hue,by:10.pt,on:light)) ) },
                          image: .system("paintpalette"),
                          color: hsbColor(hue: min(max(light.hue - 0.05, 0.1), 1.0)),
                          accessibility: "decrease saturation"),
            slider:
                    .init(action: {  rootHandler( .lighting(.apply(.values(.hsb(hue, sat, bri)),on:light))) },
                          accessibility: "change saturation"),
            trailing:
                    .init(
                        action: { rootHandler( .lighting(.increase(.hue,by:10.pt, on:light)) ) },
                        image: .system("paintpalette"),
                        color: hsbColor(hue: min(max(light.hue + 0.05, 0.1), 1.0)),
                        accessibility: "increase saturation")
        )
            .rowStyle(height: (selectedMode == .hsb && !isCollapsed) ? rowHeight : 0)
            .opacity((selectedMode == .hsb && !isCollapsed) ? 1.0 : 0.0)
    }
    private
    var satSliderRow: some View {
        slider(
            bind: $sat,
            leading:
                    .init(action: { rootHandler( .lighting(.decrease(.saturation,by:10.pt, on:light)) ) },
                          image: .system("circle.lefthalf.fill"),
                          color: hsbColor(saturation: min(max(light.saturation - 0.25, 0.1), 1.0)),
                          accessibility: "decrease saturation"),
            slider:
                    .init(action: {  rootHandler( .lighting(.apply(.values( .hsb(hue, sat, bri)),on:light))) },
                          accessibility: "change saturation"),
            trailing:
                    .init(
                        action: { rootHandler( .lighting(.increase(.saturation,by:10.pt, on:light)) ) },
                        image: .system("circle.righthalf.fill"),
                        color: hsbColor(saturation: min(max(light.saturation + 0.25, 0.1), 1.0)),
                        accessibility: "increase saturation")
        )
            .rowStyle(height: (selectedMode == .hsb && !isCollapsed) ? rowHeight : 0)
            .opacity((selectedMode == .hsb && !isCollapsed) ? 1.0 : 0.0)

    }
    private
    func imageForSlider(conf: SliderButtonConf.ButtonImage) -> Image { switch conf { case .system(let name): return Image(systemName: name) } }
    private
    func slider(
        bind: Binding<Double>,
        leading:SliderButtonConf, slider:SliderConf, trailing:SliderButtonConf) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Button {
                leading.action()
            } label: {
                imageForSlider(conf: leading.image)
                    .foregroundStyle(leading.color)
                    .accessibility(label:Text(leading.accessibility))
            }.frame(width: 24)
            Slider(value: bind){ _ in
                slider.action()
            }.accessibility(label:Text(slider.accessibility))
            Button {
                trailing.action()
            } label: {
                imageForSlider(conf: trailing.image)
                    .foregroundStyle(trailing.color)
                    .accessibility(label:Text(trailing.accessibility))
            }.frame(width: 24)
        }
    }
}
fileprivate
struct SliderButtonConf {
    let action: () -> ()
    let image: ButtonImage
    let color: Color
    let accessibility:String
    enum ButtonImage {
        case system(String)
    }
}
fileprivate
struct SliderConf {
    let action: () -> ()
    let accessibility:String
}

private
extension LightCell {
    func selected(_ mode: Light.Mode)  { selectedMode =  mode }
}

fileprivate
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func rowStyle(height:Double) -> some View {
        self.frame(height:height)
            .padding(.trailing, 15)
            .padding(.leading,  15)
            .background(material, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func isCollapsed(_ isCollapsed:Bool) -> some View {
        self.opacity(isCollapsed ? 0 : 1).frame(maxHeight: isCollapsed ? 0 : .infinity)
    }
}
fileprivate
struct Height: AnimatableModifier {
    
    init(_ height: Double) {
        self.height = height
    }
    private var height = 0.0

    var animatableData: Double {
        get { height }
        set { height = newValue }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.frame(height: height)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems me it is related to the chevron difference between its width and its height. Try making your chevron square.

Comment: I can't really see the jumping around you describe in the GIF you posted. Can you give is a detailed description of what is going wrong?

Comment: @DuncanC Yeah, look very closely at Dog House, it rises and falls slightly

Comment: I think Leo is right then. Your chevron view is probably rectangular, so as it rotates the view hight changes. Put your chevron graphic into a square image view with constant height and width constraints and it should fix it.

Comment: Just a note, if you only need to support iOS 14+ you can use [`DisclosureGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup). This doesn't solve the problem, but it's good to be aware that there is already a built-in view for this. I believe it is also possible to collapse `Section`s in a `List` (not 100% sure, and could possibly be just iOS 15).

Comment: So you guys are saying that it is the rotation effect, that creates the jump? removing it didn't affect the jumping.

Comment: I have simplified cellHeader, but the issue persists. @George_E I will have a look at DisclosureGroups, thanks.

Comment: @George_E: DisclosureGroups is not the right tool, as it forces the folded state to only be represented by a string, while I want to give the user the ability to toggle the lamp even if the cell is collapsed. but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @vikingosegundo How about the `DisclosureGroup(content:label:)` or similar initializer?

Comment: you are right, I should trust Xcode's auto completion — though after trying it out for a bit it shows the same jumping behaviour. I will investigate it further. thanks